pythonista 動画のシークについて
pythonista で作成しました。
CMTimeが間違っているのしょうか？
player.seekToTime_toleranceBefore_toleranceAfter_(zero_time, tolerance, tolerance)のところでctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: expected __Structure instance instead of CMTimのエラーなります。分かる方がいれば教えてください。
from objc_util import ObjCClass

import ctypes
from ctypes import byref

# CMTimeの定義(以前の定義を使用)
class CMTime(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('value', ctypes.c_int64),  # 値
        ('timescale', ctypes.c_int32),  # 時間スケール
        ('flags', ctypes.c_uint32),  # フラグ
        ('epoch', ctypes.c_int64),  # エポック    
    ]
    
# AVPlayer のインスタンスを取得
AVPlayer = ObjCClass('AVPlayer')

# プレーヤーオブジェクトを初期化(URLは適切に指定)
url = ObjCClass('NSURL').fileURLWithPath_('ex.MP4')
player = AVPlayer.alloc().initWithURL_(url)


zero_time = CMTime(value=0, timescale=1, flags=0, epoch=0)
tolerance = CMTime(value=1, timescale=1, flags=0, epoch=0)

player.seekToTime_toleranceBefore_toleranceAfter_(zero_time, tolerance, tolerance)
#player.play()

動画を再生した時の位置に移動します。
↓ デバック—エラー内容
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~omz-software~Pythonista3/Documents/python/move/seek02.py", line 26, in <module>
    player.seekToTime_toleranceBefore_toleranceAfter_(zero_time, tolerance, tolerance)
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5D425BFE-0B7C-4770-B8A5-3AA07C70D8D3/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/site-packages/pythonista/objc_util.py", line 898, in __call__
    res = objc_msgSend(obj.ptr, sel(self.sel_name), *args)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: expected __Structure instance instead of CMTime

